# AGOL Web App - user selects a polygon and finds Web Maps that intersect it

Tags: arcgis-online, intersection, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm working on an ArcGIS Online Web App. Basically what I want the user to be able to do is:

- Select a state from a basic US state polygon map
- From that state selection, the user then chooses a filter (e.g. the type of weather event: flood, hail, tornadoes, etc.)
- Based on the filter they choose, a window will pop up with links to different AGOL Web Maps (that I've created) for various *scenarios* of that filter type (flood, hail, etc.) for that state
- The user can then follow the link to a separate AGOL Web Map page

As an example workflow: The user opens the app, selects the state of Nebraska, chooses the filter for floods, and then sees a list of Web Map links to various flooding scenarios in Nebraska. The link they select will take them to a separate Web Map page.

The purpose of having links to separate Web Maps is to simplify the app homepage to have less layers, since there will be many maps utilized.

I am working in Web AppBuilder. I've added the state polygon layer and see many widgets for Selecting, Querying, and pulling info from a layer, but none for intersecting maps that are not included as layers in the App. I also don't see a way of filtering the results of the polygon selection (to specify desired weather event). What widgets or tools can I use to complete this workflow?

Answer (score 1):

*As an example workflow: The user opens the app, **selects the state of Nebraska**, chooses the **filter for floods**, and then sees a list of Web Map links to various flooding scenarios in Nebraska. The **link they select will take them to a separate Web Map page**.*

selects the state of Nebraska -> **Add Data widget**

chooses the filter for floods -> **Attribute table widget**, filter

sees a list of Web Map links to various flooding scenarios in Nebraska -> result will disply in the Arribute table widget.

The link they select will take them to a separate Web Map page -> Not sure what you mean here, are you planning to create seperate Web Map for each individual flood location? If so, I'd suggest you to add a new data field in the arrtibute table, the field could contain the url for seperate flood location web map.

*none for **intersecting maps that are not included as layers in the App**. I also don't see a way of filtering the results of the polygon selection (to specify desired weather event).*

intersecting maps that are not included as layers in the App - you could either add the map through the **Add Data Widget**, or pre-config the **Query Widget** to establish the connection.

I also don't see a way of filtering the results - **Attribute Table Widget**, filter

If you require more flexibility, I'd recommend you to use the developer edition, you could also find some customized widget from Esri's GeoNet.